# android studio missing Version Control Github,Git,BitBucket,Google Cloud option

Tags: android, git

I don't know why my Android Studio 3.0 now doesn't shows all my VCS option.

[image]

but when I open my Android Studio 2.2.3 it shows all options.

[image]

so why and how I can fix my Android studio 3.0

Comment: My guess is that you would need to add/enable the Git plugin from Android Studio.  Perhaps the configuration didn't carry over when you upgraded from `2.2.3`.

Comment: it appeared before, and missed when I opened a new project yesterday. but after I open the plugins it shows red in preferred options, so I disable and enable it. and this fix my problem. Thank you sir